# Can git push have a safety switch?

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging, git-push

Is there a way for git push to have a safety feature?

I've been researching [push options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/2.13.7), perhaps a default of --dry-run, that could be overridden. Maybe using an alias within git config. I'm wondering if that would be more reliable than a command line alias.

The problem I'm attempting to solve is in my previous job we worked in branches with upstream being the remote branch, not remote master. Over the years of pushing often muscle memory was created. The new job works process is upstream being remote master. 99% of the time I stop the "push" muscle memory, but 99% isn't good enough in this situation. If I change the upstream then pulling in changes becomes a little more effort. We do this many times a day, so I am keen to avoid the changing of the upstream.

Comment: I'm not that clear why you would want to be pushing straight to master and not to a branch, can you not set upstream to a remote branch and then when you are ready to move to master, adjust your development process to theirs at that point?

Comment: Hi @Nick. Thank you for the great questions. Remote master is changing hourly as many low level components are being modernised, also related packages are being released every few hours. Conflicts are common, small and usually fixed quickly.  If I waited until I was ready to move to master, the hit would be from many change sets. I guess I could rebase in small amounts, checking for issues as I go. The down side may be that after a day or two the changes are "baked in", and people may be less flexible in what fixes may be possible.

Comment: In that scenario I'd probably still be using a remote branch  and rebasing on top of Master regularly (it just feels nicer/safer!)

Comment: Hi @Nick. That sounds good. I'm guessing a fetch then rebase using the args origin/master ?  I'll need to research. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write a pre-push hook which can block or ask for confirmation if the updated remote branch is `master`

Comment: Confirmed.I did a simpler case of any push. I copied the sample hook called pre-push. Modified to look for variable GIT_PUSH_SAFETY, otherwise echo   "GIT_PUSH_SAFETY not set, not pushing". When you really want to push  GIT_PUSH_SAFETY=1 git push bla bla